# Updating pgsql table setting new value depending on row previous value

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Basically, I want to update a column of numeric value, setting it to its previous value multiplied by a constant, but for an entire table worth of rows that meet the criteria, any help would be appreciated

edit: also every row has values independent from each other

edit 2: I'm looking for something like `UPDATE table SET rowsColumnValue TO rowsColumnValue * constant WHERE differentColumnusedAsIdentifier = someNumber` but that doesn't set every row to the same number, but to its previous value in that column multiplied by the given constant

edit 3: basically I want that if in a row a column value is 2 and in another one is 4, now they become 4 and 8

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. But now I'm confused. You want to set every row to the same value, or to a value depending on what it was before?

Comment: Intuitively, "previous value" is time-based, ie. the value it had before the operation. That's not what you mean then?

Comment: to a value depending on what it was before

Comment: like if a row's column was 2 and another was 4, and the constant was 2, the new values would be 4 and 8

Comment: "a row's column"? Do you mean the value in the column or the column name? These terms aren't making any sense. If you need to update multiple columns you need to separate them by commas in your update. Aside from that, I can't really figure out what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Saving calculated data is usually a bad design. And what you want to do just might not be possible in query. You want to calculate values based on other data but then you also want to change that other data at the same time. I expect VBA code manipulating recordset object could manage this edit. Your title says 'previous' value but looks like you really mean the 'current' value. Are these values in two columns of the same record?

Comment: Ayush responded got what i meant and answered accordingly below, but thanks so much for trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this and let me know if it helps:

```
    Update table_name set column_name = column_name * constant
[where column = condition]
```

Comment: thanks it totally did, i thought it wasn't working but that actually was another mistake in my code, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're Welcome!